# What does 「だける」means in this sentence?

Tags: translation, words

Found this in book that I've just read

> きっとその魅力がわかていた**だける**かと思います

Answer (score 2):

> きっとその魅力がわかていただけるかと思います

It is

> きっとその魅力がわかって**いただける**かと思います

which is a potential form of "いただく".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suppose you mean **わかって**いただける in your original question.

> きっとその魅力が**わかって**いただけるかと思います